# Why am I getting a spurious white pixel when I render a texture in SDL?

Tags: c, graphics, sdl-2, game-development

I'm using SDL2 to draw some stuff on screen. Here is some code:

```
#include <SDL.h>

void main()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 500, 500, 0);

    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    SDL_Texture *texture;
    {
        SDL_Surface *window_surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
        Uint32 pixel_format = window_surface->format->format;
        SDL_Surface *surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceWithFormat(0, 48, 48, 8, pixel_format);
        texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
        SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
        SDL_FreeSurface(window_surface);
    }

    SDL_Rect target_rectangle;
    target_rectangle.x = 100;
    target_rectangle.y = 100;
    target_rectangle.w = 48;
    target_rectangle.h = 48;

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, 0, 50, 50, 0);

    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, 0, &target_rectangle);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        
    SDL_Event event;
    while(1)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                return;
                break;
            }
        }

        SDL_Delay(10);
    }
}
```

The code creates some dummy blank texture `texture`. I get the same behavior with a texture loaded from a bitmap file. These lines are the important ones:

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, 0, 50, 50, 0);

SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, 0, &target_rectangle);

SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

So draw a line somewhere in white pixels, and then copy the dummy texture to the screen, and display it all. When I do this, I get a white pixel at the bottom right of the texture.

[image]

As I said, I also get this when the texture comes from a bitmap using code like this:

```
SDL_Surface *bitmap_surface = SDL_LoadBMP("test.bmp");
SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, bitmap_surface);
SDL_FreeSurface(bitmap_surface);
```

[image]

Comment: I've had this exact same problem, and I think this is a bug in the OpenGL implementation of `SDL_RenderDrawLine`. Try using a software renderer (`SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer`) and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @EmanuelP Yup, that fixed it. Thanks.